# Proof related to quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Suppose that m and n are integers such that both the quadratic equations 
$x^2 + mx − n = 0$
and 
$x^2 − mx + n = 0$ have integer roots.

How to prove that n is divisible by 6?

Comment: Have you tried the quadratic formula?

Comment: How does that help? @columbus8myhw

Comment: You know that $\frac{-m\pm\sqrt{m^2+4n}}2$ is an integer, from the first quadratic. That tells you that $m^2+4n$ is a square, for instance, because otherwise $\sqrt{m^2+4n}$ — and hence the roots — would be irrational.

Comment: Are these equations simlutaneous?

Comment: @ShashiDwivedi I expect them to be separate equations with separate roots, so it's probably no.

Comment: As an example, take $m=5,n=6$. We have $x^2+5x-6$ has roots $-6,1$, and $x^2-5x+6$ has roots $2,3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the quadratic formula tells you that $m^2-4n,m^2$ and $m^2+4n$ must be perfect squares.

Now, use that perfect squares are only $0,1 \mod 3$ to show that $3|n$.

Use that perfect squares are only $0,1,4,9 \mod 16$ to show that $2|n$.

EDIT:

Okay, as it seems not so easy to finish from here, I will do it for you:

First, we prove $3|n$.

Assume $3 \not \mid n$. Then $m^2,m^2-4n,m^2+4n$ all leave different residues $\mod 3$. So one of them must be $2 \mod 3$. Absurd! Hence $3|n$.

Now, we want to prove $2|n$.

Assume $2 \not \mid n$. Then $m^2,m^2-4n,m^2+4n$ all leave different residues $\mod 16$ but have the same residue $\mod 4$.
But there are only two possible odd ($1$ and $9$) and two possible even ($0$ and $4$)residues of perfect squares $\mod 16$.

So again we derived a contradiction and conclude $2|n$ i.e. $6|n$. Hence the claim.

Comment: Please explain clearly....what do you mean by "show"...how did you get it?

Comment: Try to do it yourself! Just check the different possibilities of residues for $m$ and $n$ $\mod 3/16$.

Comment: I agree with Sanchayan Dutta, this is not really an answer just a hint.  I too am having trouble getting the result from what you suggest.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it is sufficiently clear now..